# What is best way to attach deck balusters?

Tags: deck, outdoor, decking, railing

I am going to build a railing around my wall.

One of my friend hired a contractor who installed balusters between two 2x4s. But now those spindles coming out. They first drilled a hole of 3/4” in every 4” in both top and bottom 2x4 wood. Then installed spindles in those holes. We see the top 2x4 crowned little bit over time that’s why spindles coming out from those places.

Now I am going to build railing around my wall too, what is the best way?

Drill hole with 1” deeper
Or use connectors( showing in image)[image]

Another way

Please advise.[image]

Comment: This is a matter of opinion (about the procedure, cost, and appearance). Both systems are viable. I have lots of experience with each. Warped lumber is the actual problem in the scenario you described, and is a problem with either mounting strategy.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is a "preference" thing: both of these solutions will work if properly installed. The holes drilled for baluster install in the top and bottom rails should be deep enough that the balusters cannot flex out with normal slight movement of the wood. This indicates your previous install was improperly done.

The install in your second picture with connectors works well, it limits the movement (even rotation) of the balusters. This is my preference, my deck is built this way now. This can help on the stair railing where the holes method would require even deeper holes due to the diagonal, to keep the balusters from falling out the shallow side.

Ultimately, this comes down to preference and cost tolerance.

Comment: I agree. I've done both numerous times, and a crowned rail is more a problem with the rail than the baluster attachment mechanism. The rail should be replaced, I suppose.

Comment: @fredric, one of friend said  drill deep hole and use Sikaflex which prevent rail in any movement. Will this work ?

Comment: Probably; I haven't used it but in reading, it's a "professional-grade" sealant/adhesive. Whether you water-seal or not, you might have issues with water getting in the hole beside the baluster and causing damage over time as it gets wet and dries. Sikaflex could help prevent much of that water from getting in the hole, but on the other hand would keep it from drying out as quickly/effectively.